# Smoothing arbitrary curve changes

Tags: interpolation

I'm a programmer, my math knowledges are very limited, so if my post is misplaced - just let me know

There is an arbitrary curve with regular step. The value at specific point should be changed to a specified new one. I need to adapt/interpolate nearby curve values to adapt a new value. I've implemented a simple    linear interpolation (see image). Maybe with hermite transition it can look better.

However, it works bad. For example the curve describes a character foot motion. Ok, the foot is landed (horizontal curve piece), then it's elevated again (my interpolation of new value) and returns back to earth. This "added new motion" looks absolute unnatural

So I need more "intellectual" interpolation that preserves a curve shape. For example above we need a same "stay" right (e.g. do not change right side at all) and a monotonous slope at left side.

Is (or how) such interpolation technique known in math?

Thx

Igors

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like [spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) or [monotone cubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation)?

Comment: not a spline exactly because I need to modify/adjust nearby points to a new value (not to interpolate values inbetween). But. yes, I want to keep monotony to preserve curve "mimics", For example, if a new value is in range from previous to next one - maybe do nothing. Otherwise modfy left/right slope(s)